# Can a GitHub README be redirected to another location?

Tags: http, github, redirect

I am migrating a series of GitHub READMEs into a different location. It would be nice if the files at the original location could be redirected to the new one (for those folks who have the old pages bookmarked/linked etc).

Is this possible within GitHub?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible to do any sort of redirect on GitHub.  This feature, if it were implemented, would unfortunately be subject to abuse as people redirected users from the main page of the repo elsewhere.

However, if your README is a symlink to a file in another directory and otherwise named appropriately, GitHub will follow the symlink when it renders the page, provided the path is relative to your repository.

Comment: When you say: *provided the path is relative to your repository* Do you mean `../../../another repository/G-H-Pages/instructions.html` or do you mean a sub-directory within the same repository?

Comment: It has to be within the same repository.  It would be a security problem to resolve URLs across repositories, since the repository is a trust boundary.

Comment: It's not a security issue if it's a relative directory within the ownership. For example `../../../my other repository` as long as it stays within `https://giithub/me` is OK. If it was changing to `../../../../https://thedarknet/mindgames.com` then yes it would be a security risk. Anyway understood that your "relative" means within the same repository whereas mine is "relative" to the root directory which is `https:/github.com/me`. The definition is all relative I guess :) Upvote for taking time to respond!

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the case.  If `me` is an organization, then just because Alice has access to `me/project-a` doesn't mean she should be able to refer to the rendering of `me/project-b`, to which she might not even have access.  Or, if she knows that the latter repo refers to the former, she could include false or inaccurate information if this were allowed.  There are also other technical considerations (such as different repos being stored on different machines) that make this technically infeasible as well.

Comment: Ahh... My organization only has three people Me, Myself and I. That said I still need `sudo` powers to install software. Maybe one day **GitHub** will allow Administrators like `sudo` to with root privileges. As far as different repos being on different servers, that I can't comment on (above my pay grade).